# Adding sections to UITableView in 'Edit' Mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a basic list workout app right now that keeps track of workouts and then the exercises for each workout. I want to extend the current 'editing' mode of a TableViewController to allow for more advanced editing options. Here is what I have so far:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, I am inserting a section at the top of the table view so that the title of the workout can be edited. The problem I am facing is twofold:

1. There is no animation when the edit button is tapped anymore.
2. When you try to swipe right on one of the exercises (Squat or Bench press) the entire section containing exercises disappears.

I start by triggering one of two different functions on the setEditing function, to either switch to read mode or edit mode based on whether the boolean editing returns true or false.

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    if editing {
        switchToEditMode()
    } else {
        switchToReadMode()
    }
}
```

Then I either insert the "addTitle" section (the text field seen in the second image) to an array called tableSectionsKey which I use to determine how to display the table (seen further below), and then reload the table data.

```
func switchToEditMode(){
    tableSectionsKey.insert("addTitle", at:0)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func switchToReadMode(){
    tableSectionsKey.remove(at: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is my tableView data method. Basically the gist of it is that I have the array called tableSectionsKey I mentioned above, and I add strings that relate to sections based on what mode I'm in and what information should be displayed. Initially it just has "addExercise", which related to the "Add exercise to routine" cell

```
class WorkoutRoutineTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var tableSectionsKey = ["addExercise"]
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad I add the "exercise" section (for list of exercises) if the current workout routine has any, and I add the addTitle section if it's in new mode, which is used to determine if the view controller is being accessed from an add new workout button or a from a list of preexisting workouts (so to determine if the page is being used to create a workout or update an existing one)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if workoutRoutine.exercises.count > 0 {
        tableSectionsKey.insert("exercise", at:0)
    }
    if mode == "new" {             
        tableSectionsKey.insert("addTitle", at: 0)
    }
}
```

Then in the cellForRowAt function I determine how to style the cell based on how the section of the table relates with an index in the tableSectionsKey array

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let section = indexPath.section
    let sectionKey = tableSectionsKey[section]
    let cellIdentifier = sectionKey + "TableViewCell"
    
    switch sectionKey {
    case "addTitle":
        
        guard let addTitleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? AddTitleTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Was expecting cell of type AddTitleTableViewCell.")
        }
        setUpAddTitleTableViewCell(for: addTitleCell)
        
        return addTitleCell
        
    case "exercise":
        
        guard let exerciseCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ExerciseTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Was expecting cell of type ExerciseTableViewCell.")
        }
        let exercise = workoutRoutine.exercises[indexPath.row]
        setUpExerciseTableViewCell(for: exerciseCell, with: exercise)
        
        return exerciseCell
        
    case "addExercise":
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        
        return cell
        
    default:
        fatalError("Couldn't find section: \(section), in WorkoutRoutineTableView" )
    }
}

private func setUpExerciseTableViewCell(for cell: ExerciseTableViewCell, with exercise: Exercise) {
    let titleText = exercise.name
    let detailsText = "\(exercise.sets)x\(exercise.reps) - \(exercise.weight)lbs"
    cell.titleLabel.text = titleText
    cell.detailsLabel.text = detailsText
}

private func setUpAddTitleTableViewCell(for cell: AddTitleTableViewCell) {
    cell.titleTextField.delegate = self
    if (workoutRoutine.title != nil) {
        cell.titleTextField.text = workoutRoutine.title
    }
    // Set the WorkoutRoutineTableViewController property 'titleTextField' to the 'titleTextField' found in the addTitleTableViewCell
    self.titleTextField = cell.titleTextField
}
```

This isn't all of my code but I believe it is all of the code that could be relevant to this problem.

Comment: You are asking two completely unrelated questions and you are not providing any information related to the 2nd issue. So I suggest you narrow this question down to just the 1st issue related to loss of animations when going into and out of edit mode. Then, if needed, post another question specific to the problem with swiping one of the exercises. Be sure to clearly explain when you are seeing and when and include relevant just to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation issue is due to the use of `reloadData`. You need to replace the uses of `reloadData` with calls to insert or delete just the one section.

```
func switchToEditMode(){
    tableSectionsKey.insert("addTitle", at:0)
    let section = IndexSet(integer: 0)
    self.tableView.insertSections(section, with: .left) // use whatever animation you want
}

func switchToReadMode(){
    tableSectionsKey.remove(at: 0)
    let section = IndexSet(integer: 0)
    self.tableView.deleteSections(section, with: .left) // use whatever animation you want
}
```